# How to compile OpenSSH sourcecode into ios app

Tags: ios, openssh

I had already written an `iOS` app that uses `OpenSSH`, but this requires a device jailbreak and the install of `OpenSSH` in `Cydia`. For now, I am finding a way to get the `OpenSSH` source code to compile into my `iOS` app, and to distribute this App in Apple Enterprise Developer 'In House' way. If this works, no jailbreak would be required.

But I can not find any sample or source code which can be integrated into an `XCode iOS` device project. Any information is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OpenSSH, you could use [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) if you need a server, or [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/) if a client is sufficient. For libssh2, x2on has already made the migration effort. You can get the repo here: https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS.

If you intend to use libssh, beware that it's LGPL licensed, so it's not compatible with the AppStore (but should be compatible with in house distribution).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i had already know libssh, but i can not use lbissh to connect my server, which OpenSSH is work for it. so i think i should continue looking for the way that integrated OpenSSH.